# zonal statistics in Python crashes

Tags: python, zonal-statistics

I have a python script that works (it's worked for several other projects in the past and it worked for my current project initially). But whenever I run it, Python crashes sporadically. It would go through some iterations (I'm calculating zonal stats as table for 540 files for 10 countries, so over 5000 files in all, it's worked fine for the first country and now it's not working).

I'm not getting an error message or anything, it's just stopping. I mean I would get the:

> > > ========= RESTART =================

but that's it. Then I would click back to the script, click F5 and restart it, it would stop randomly and I'll restart it again. I have no idea why it's doing this and there's no way that I can babysit the program.

HELP?!

Comment: Maybe you should provide your script as well as some small part of the data to play with.

Comment: If you put a print statement on the first line of your Python script you would at least be able to see if your script was starting to run (or not).  I'm assuming that you are using ArcGIS 10.1 but, in any event, can you let us know your software and version, please?